# What is the right method of validating .NET Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I'm searching on everywhere but just couldn't find a good example or text about this subject.

I would like to check for example the username and password validity when a user presses the OK button in a dialog.

Should I do this in the closing event, and cancel the dialog close if the validation fails? Or set the `DialogResult` to none instead of OK. These all seem kinda the wrong way to do it. I also saw the `Validated` and `Validating` events but aren't those for only validating a single control for valid input?

How can I check more controls together when the OK button is pressed, and cancel the form closing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to do. If you want to verify that the user entered something that could possibly be a valid username/password, you could use the Validating events (e.g. make sure it is long enough, etc). If you want to verify that the username/password corresponds to a valid account, then you have to wait until they hit the OK button and check the credentials. If they are bad then you can throw up a message box (or whatever) and prevent the dialog from closing (DialogResult.None).

Comment: Basically that was what I wanted to do and `DialogResult.None` worked too, but wasn't sure if that was the right way to do it since it doesn't seem very readable to me that a `none` result value of something actually cancels the dialog. But I guess there aren't any other choices

Comment: +1: I read the question again and it is about "business validation" not about "input validation" so this is correct answer.

Comment: But you do need to call Close if your validation fails?

Comment: Not exactly, I wanted a modal popup where if I press OK and the login is correct I close it and enable the main frame, and with cancel I close the application. If the validation fails I display error message and let the user try again

Answer (score 1):

Each control offers `Validating` event. In this event you can implement validation of a single control. By default this validation is triggered when control lose focus. In contrast to `Validated` event, handler of this event receives `CancelEventArgs` so if validation fails you can cancel current operation (losing focus).

When you want to deal with complex validations you can set `AutoValidate` property of your form to `AutoValidate.Disable`. This will disable implicit validation (default behavior described before). Instead you will have to call `ValidateChildren` to trigger explicit validation of all child controls.